# How can convert a XML document into a Js String?

Tags: javascript, xml, string

I need this XML document (register.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<All>
<Shoe>
    <Name>All Stars</Name>
    <BrandName>Converse</BrandName>
    <ReleaseDate>10/2/08</ReleaseDate>
</Shoe>
<Shoe>
    <Name>All Star1s</Name>
    <BrandName>Converse1</BrandName>
    <ReleaseDate>11/2/08</ReleaseDate>
</Shoe>
```

Store in this Javascript variable:

```
var ShoesXML
```

Because I actually create a html table from this Js variable that contains XML data this way:
`

```
var ShoesXML = "<All><Shoe><Name>All Stars</Name><BrandName>Converse</BrandName><ReleaseDate>10/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe><Shoe><Name>All Star1s</Name><BrandName>Converse1</BrandName><ReleaseDate>11/2/08</ReleaseDate></Shoe></All>";
$(document).ready(function() {  
  xmlDoc=$.parseXML( ShoesXML );
  $(xmlDoc).find("Shoe").each(function(i, n) {
        var html = "<tr>\n" + 
            "<td><span>" + $(n).find("Name").text() + "</span></td>\n" +
            "<td>" +  $(n).find("BrandName").text() + "</td>\n" +
            "<td>" + $(n).find("ReleaseDate").text() + "</td>\n" + 
            "</tr>";
        $("table.shoetable tbody").append(html);
    });
});
```

THE PROBLEM IS that with this way

```
var ShoesXML = "<All><Shoe><Name>All Stars</Name><BrandName>Converse</BrandName><ReleaseDate>10/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe><Shoe><Name>All Star1s</Name><BrandName>Converse1</BrandName><ReleaseDate>11/2/08</ReleaseDate></Shoe></All>";
```

I'm setting the value manually, but I need to get it from the actual (register.xml) document and then store it in:

```
var ShoesXML
```

For later use.

Comment: Still vague. Elaborate more!

Comment: which part confuses you?

Comment: This part: _But this way, as you can suppost, when I "edit" the XML, doesn't work cause the variable still with the default value, and everytime the variable gets initialized with the default value, so I need to read the XML document and then store it in_

Comment: I think you should just read the value from a server API call, instead on the string fixed in the code like now. And then add an API call that allow to save changes on the XML.

Comment: okay, what I was trying to say is that with var ShoesXML = "<All><Shoe><Name>All Stars</Name><BrandName>Converse</BrandName><ReleaseDate>10/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe><Shoe><Name>All Star1s</Name><BrandName>Converse1</BrandName><ReleaseDate>11/2/08</ReleaseDate></Shoe></All>"; I'm setting the value, not reading it from a XML document, I need find a way to getting the value from a XML document and then store it in that variable, for later use.